# child elements cannot be hided once shown except using .toggle() method in .each()

Tags: jquery

This question basically arose while I was trying to answer one more question.

The question is simple - I have markup as below:

```
<div class="parent">
    Parent
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="Element 1"/>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <span>Element 3</span>
    <input type="button" class="hideParent" value="Hide Children"/>
</div>
```

and the below `CSS` to `hide` all the child elements of `.parent` `div`

```
.parent>input,.parent>div,.parent>span {
    display: none;
}
```

Now what I was trying to do is on `click` of `div.parent` I want to display all the `children` of `div.parent` and I have below `JS` for that.

```
$('.parent').on('click',function(){
   $(this).children().show(); 
});
```

and as you can see there is a button inside `div.parent` which basically is to `hide` the children of `div.parent` again.

In various ways I tried to `hide` the `child` and to my utter surprise, none worked except `.toggle()`!  Why this behavior is happening on below 3 approaches? Anyone have idea on this?

Different approach I tried for `hiding` elements:

**Using `.hide()`**

```
$('.hideParent').on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('.parent').children())
   //Logs all the children
   $(this).closest('.parent').children().hide();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zxyrraft/)**

---

**Using `.each()` and `.css` to change `display:none`**

```
$('.hideParent').on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('.parent').children())
   $(this).closest('.parent').children().each(function(){
       console.log('here');//Comes here 5 times as there are 5 elements
       $(this).css('display','none !important'); 
   })
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zxyrraft/1/)**

---

**Using `.each()` and `.hide()`**

```
$('.hideParent').on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('.parent').children())
   $(this).closest('.parent').children().each(function(){
       console.log('here');//Again I can see this
       $(this).hide();
   })
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zxyrraft/2/)**

**But works fine using `.toggle()` but only when used with `$.each()`**

```
$('.parent').on('click',function(){
   $(this).children().toggle();
});

$('.hideParent').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('.parent').children().each(function(){
       console.log('here');
       $(this).children().toggle();
   })
   //$(this).closest('.parent').children().toggle(); //Doesn't work
});
```

**[Working DEMO with `$.each()`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zxyrraft/4/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of event propagation, clicking the button will also trigger the click event attached to the `parent` which will again set the children to show.

Stopping the click event's propagation from the `button` will solve the issue like

```
$('.parent').on('click', function () {
    $(this).children().show();
});

$('.hideParent').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.parent').children().hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/219troyr/1/)

---

Your last solution with `toggle` is not really working, the `hideParent` click handler is not doing anything as there are no grand children for the `parent` element. The actual hide/show is done by the `toggle` call in the `parent` click handler

Comment: Oh yea.. Thanks Arun but why it did not work in `$.each` for `.hide` and worked for `.toggle`? I mean in my question, I've given many scenarios where only one worked.. Its really confusing behavior.. I would be great if you explain for each situation.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao see the update - if you just remove the hideParent handler then too it works.. but not in the way you want

Comment: Perfect Arun.. That makes sense now.. I cracked my head like anything for this question.. Thanks alot for explanation.. :)